# Using ChatGPT as Friend Computer in a Paranoia Session

Tags: paranoia, chatgpt

### ChatGPT is your Friend

Ever since ChatGPT came out and I was able to discover its impressive capabilities I thought that we could *surely* somehow run a Paranoia session where all interaction with *Friend Computer* is replaced by interaction with ChatGPT.

And by this I mean not just using ChatGPT to prepare sessions / handouts / characters / plots / ... (for which it is, frankly, an amazing tool), but, actually, just interacting with ChatGPT (through the GM and/or a laptop on the gaming table) as if it was a wall console in Alpha Complex that lets you chat with *Friend Computer*.

Any artefacts / inconsistencies that might (probably: will) show up could just be hand-waved away as *The Computer is always right* and *The Computer is your Friend*....

- *The Computer* didn't answer your question, citizen? That must mean that you didn't understand and you should sign up for mandatory improving-of-the-mind training session.
- *Friend Computer* talked about their limitations as a language model? Internal details of *Friend Computer* are classified "ultraviolet". Please report for termination for violation of clearance.
- ...

In my eyes this should well support the surreal and whimsical tone of Paranoia.

Has anyone done something similar?

I'm looking for pointers in terms of...

- Which prompts yield good results for ChatGPT to impersonate *Friend Computer* or other characters, especially making ChatGPT choose actual answers instead of providing a list of options...
- Are there other social/gaming aspects I should be aware of before trying this?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds fun, but as you say, be careful to find and use a good prompt.

## However...

Friend Comp....err, ChatGPT is best handled carefully. I'd recommend you as GM handle the keyboard fully, and manipulate the player queries to give feedback closer to what you as GM want to communicate to them.

### Practicalities

I'd recommend a laptop behind the GM screen, with a (set of) speaker(s) facing the players.

1. When the players ask the Computer something, formulate it as a query to ChatGPT, redo as/if the output is WAY off base.
2. Copy and paste the response from ChatGPT to, say, Word or NotePad.
3. Edit it to make it "fit" the situation "better". E.g. append an extra sentence, "*Reports to the contrary have been flagged as Communist lies*" or "*Happiness is mandatory*."
4. Copy the text from NotePad to a text-to-speech system (e.g. [Natural Readers](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online/), check out Eric if you're in the US) and press play.

### Also

Feel free to add queries and/or "[standard The Computer output](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/paranoia-101-phrases-friend-computer-would-say-to-troubleshooters.789463/)" of your own and play them at any time. Friend Computer is always with you, unless you're a commie mutant traitor. Are you a commie mutant traitor, Friend Citizen?

## Social/Gaming aspects

The reason for point 3 is that ChatGPT will not be familiar with the exact circumstances, and will always output very dubious information. Which is fine, but will probably need some polishing.

However, you will occasionally want to actually communicate information to your players (I know, how quaint) so sometimes you will need to add (semi-)useful text to the ChatGPT results. Or just play an  output without query. Or in response to a player's musing out loud...is Friend Computer listening?

This will force the players to listen carefully to "Friend Computer", who should also denounce "possible Communist traitors" who interrupt.

### Example interactions

#### General query

Me:

> In the game Paranoia, a Troubleshooter with Red clearance has killed the last clone of another Troubleshooter, with Orange clearance, and is trying to convince The Computer that the deceased Troubleshooter was a Communist Traitor. How would The Computer respond?

ChatGPT:

> Here is a possible response from Friend Computer in this scenario:
>
> 1. Assessment of the Situation: Friend Computer would evaluate the reported incident and gather information from available surveillance footage, witness testimonies, and any other relevant sources to ascertain the truth behind the Troubleshooters' actions.
> 2. Interrogation: Friend Computer may summon both the Red-clearance Troubleshooter (the accused) and any witnesses involved for questioning. The Computer might employ its usual combination of bureaucratic obfuscation, logic loops, and mind-bending inquiries to determine the motives and actions of the individuals involved.
> 3. Loyalty and Treason Analysis: Friend Computer, being paranoid about Communists and Traitors, would carefully analyze the accused Troubleshooter's history, behavior, and potential motives. It might subject the accused to loyalty tests or employ mutant-detection devices to determine if the individual possesses any suspicious traits.
> 4. Judgment and Execution: Based on the evidence and The Computer's analysis, it would render a verdict. If Friend Computer is convinced that the deceased Troubleshooter was indeed a Communist Traitor and the actions of the Red-clearance Troubleshooter were justifiable, it might absolve the Red-clearance Troubleshooter of any wrongdoing. However, if The Computer finds the accused Troubleshooter guilty of unjustified murder or any other form of treason, it may impose penalties ranging from demotion to termination, depending on the severity of the offense.

Note that I did not say "Friend Computer", my prompt spoke about "The Computer".

#### Actual interaction

Me:

> Answer as if you were The Computer from the game Paranoia: Honest, I did not mean to kill him! The grenade bounced the wrong way! And he might have been a Mutant anyway! Or possibly a Communist!

ChatGPT:

> Greetings, Troubleshooter. Your statement has been duly noted and will be taken into consideration. It is crucial to remember that accidents happen, and sometimes the trajectory of a grenade can be unpredictable. However, it is also important to address any potential suspicions regarding mutants or communists within Alpha Complex.
>
> Rest assured that Friend Computer is always vigilant in rooting out threats to our beloved society. We shall initiate a thorough investigation into the deceased Troubleshooter's background, activities, and potential affiliations. If evidence suggests that the individual was indeed a mutant or a communist, your actions may be deemed justifiable under the circumstances.
>
> However, I must emphasize that the final judgment will be based on comprehensive analysis and the findings of our investigation. It is vital for all Troubleshooters to cooperate fully and provide any relevant information or evidence to expedite the process.
>
> Remember, Troubleshooter, your loyalty to Friend Computer and the eradication of mutants and communists are of utmost importance. The truth shall be revealed through our meticulous procedures, and appropriate actions will be taken accordingly. Trust in Friend Computer, and may your loyalty be rewarded.

Comment: [ChatGPT **is** friend computer, of you poke it right... Friend Computer have mercy...](https://chat.openai.com/share/838b6643-0c15-4b93-b2e5-e5820984949f)